# Load A View Controller programmatically from a UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, viewcontroller

I am using the following from within a class to call a UIViewController. The UIViewController loads, but then becomes unresponsive after loading.

```
let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

let homeC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
"ViewJoeProfileController") as? ViewJoeProfileController
    if homeC != nil {
        homeC!.view.frame = (self.window!.frame)
        self.window!.addSubview(homeC!.view)
        self.window!.bringSubview(toFront: homeC!.view)
    } 
}
```

Any suggestions to make the UIViewController being loaded responsive would really help!

Comment: why are you using window? if you want to present a viewcontroler from another viewcontroler you can simply do this func `present(VC, animated: true: completion: nil)` , https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621380-present

Comment: Check this `Each window typically has a single root view object (managed by a corresponding view controller) that contains all of the other views representing your content. Using a single root view simplifies the process` it's from apple!!. I feel like you are doing something wrong. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingWindows/CreatingWindows.html

Comment: So if you wanna push/pop a `VC` you would probably do that from another `VC, navigationController or TabbarController`... you probably don't need to deal with the window unless you are setting a `rootViewController`

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically want to add to the window, you should do it the proper way and add the whole ViewController:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {
    guard let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds) else { return true }
    if let homeC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewJoeProfileController") as? ViewJoeProfileController {
        window.rootViewController = mainViewController
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }

    return true
}
```

But honestly that structure still doesn't seem correct. Why are you adding a view to the window, instead of using an initial view controller and then adding to itsviews, or segueing to different ViewControllers?.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this I need to make root View Controller

```
let storyBoard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewJoeProfileController") as! ViewJoeProfileController
let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
nav.isNavigationBarHidden = true
self.window?.rootViewController=nav
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```